# Cropping Geotiff with gdalwarp

Tags: dem, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp

I downloaded a geotiff from the recently published 25m-DEM of the European Union (see: http://courses.neteler.org/eu-dem-new-digital-surface-model-at-25m/). One tile has about 5GB so I would like to crop it to a smaller extend. I'm trying to use `gdalwarp` but I can't figure out the correct commands ...

Here's my **bounding box**: `N48 W15 S43 E5`

This is **the command I tried** :

```
gdalwarp -of gtiff -t_srs EPSG:3857 -te 5 43 15 48 input.tif output.tif
```

This is the **error message** that `gdalwarp` returned:

> "Creating output file that is 0P x 0L. ERROR 1: Attempt to create 0x0
>   dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero."

Could anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 12):

The coordinates of the target extent have to be expressed in the target SRS:

> **-te xmin ymin xmax ymax:**
>       set georeferenced extents of output file to be created (in target SRS).

Being...

```
>cs2cs +init=EPSG:4326 +to +init=EPSG:3857
5 43
556597.45       5311971.85 0.00
15 48
1669792.36      6106854.83 0.00
```

the command should be something like:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -te 556597.45 5311971.85 1669792.36 6106854.83 input.tif output.tif
```

Comment: I exported the tif but as a result I'm getting strange "gridded" artefacts on the image. Is there a way to avoid nearest neighbor resampling in gdalwarp? Or could this have another reason? Thank you!

Comment: You have to use the `-r` option: http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html

Answer (score 2):

the `-te` flag expects the coordinates to be projected in the -t_srs CRS. EPSG:3857 has as a unit meters, and your inputs are most likely degrees.

to obtain the correct values gdalwarp needs you can project from one coordinate system to antoher using the cs2cs program:

`cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +init=epsg:3857`

The default order of values are  x-y or E-N